# HTTP Request to remove record and then remove obj from array Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-resource

This question came out after solving [**this problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366105/remove-object-from-array-filtered-by-an-id-vuejs) thanks to @nils and I hope someone can help me!

Actually I have a list of records and I can select some of then and remove those with one click.

The code above is working as it should be but I am not sure if what I am doing is right or if it can break any time!

So there I doing the HTTP Request to delete the record inside of the Array.filter()... is that right? I feels that it is quite not right!

```
deleteSelected() {
  this.list = this.list.filter(function(val, i) {
    var id = val.id.toString();

    if (this.selected.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      return true;
    } else {

      this.$http.delete('/sources/' + id)
        .then(function() {
          return false;
        }, function() {
          return true;
        });

    }
  }, this);

  this.selected = [];
},
```

The array `this.list` is where are my list of objects and the `this.selected` array contains the ID's selected to be removed.

Then if the HTTP request goes ok I remove the obj and if not I keep it!

How do you think is a good way to do that?

**---------EDIT---------**

Adding a JSBin to be clear what I need!

**Actually I just found a problem on my script... It does not wait for the ajax response to remove the item from the array so if some of those record couldn't be deleted it is gonna be removed from the array as well**

Somebody?

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/fikahi/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I though that code does not worked but I found a good solution!

It's not working because it is a mass delete so each delete is one request but I've made everyone at once and the script does not wait for the answer to remove the item from the list! If the record does not end up deleted by some validation it will be removed from the list as well!

So what I did is send all delete requests and when the last one finish I make a new request to get to entire list updated!

Here is the code:

```
// block the records list
$(this.$els.dataGrid).block();

// init a counter
var itemsProcessed = 0;

// get length of records to be deleted
var length = this.selected.length;

// looping to delete one for each
this.selected.forEach((item) => {

  // removeLossReasonById() is a method that mand the HTTP DELETE request and then()
  this.removeLossReasonById(item).then((response) => {

    // if does not delete for any reason show a notify
    if (!response.ok)
      $.Notification.error(response.data);

    // increment the counter
    itemsProcessed++;

    // if is the last iteration it's gonna unblock the records list and clear my array of items to be removed
    if (itemsProcessed === length) {
      this.selected = [];
      this.getLossReasons().then(() => $(this.$els.dataGrid).unblock());
    }
  });
});
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

What I do is something like:

```
<ul>
     <li v-for="item in list" @click="deleteItem(item)"></li>
</ul>
```

So you basically pass the list item to the delete method which in turn does:

```
deleteItem: function(item) {
    # Ajax delete request
    .successs(
        this.list.$remove(item);
    )
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: It's not what I need Liren! I just added a JS Bin to be clear what I need!! Look that if do you know how to do!

Comment: Can't test it right now, but I did try removing your ajax request and that makes the code work. So probably look into what's going on the backend of that request.

Comment: Yes it does! But as I am new at that front end framework thing I would like to know if thats is the right way to do so. I had put it before inside a FOR LOOPING and somebody told that it's not right... So I change it and now I would like to now if it's ok now =)

Comment: Actually I found the problem =/.... if some of those registers can't be removed whatever why the item item removed from the array... it doesn't wait for the HTTP response...